# What should I choose

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, sqldeveloper

I want to install Ubuntu but I am confused between 14.04 ("Trusty Tahr") LTS and 14.10 "Utopic Unicorn". 
Which one I should choose as I am a developer for Android so I could have a completely stable environment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'complete set of stable entertainment'?

Comment: This depends on your personal preference. But development of Android is not something that makes a difference in this. The only reason to go for 14.04 is stability but that does not mean you can not run software from 14.10 or 15.04 in it. Besides that: virtualbox lets you run 14.10 in 14.04.

Comment: @Rinzwind there might be differences in versions relating to tools for Android which could make a difference in Android development. Are different Java SDK versions distributed in 14.04 and 14.10? What are the differences? I don't know enough about this/would need to do some research but I think there is an answer to this question. It would probably be 14.04 (for stability) unless if there are a lot of new features in 14.10 versions of programs for Android-related tasks.

Comment: @Ads20000 virtualbox fixes that argument.

Comment: @Rinzwind Visualization is never a great solution especially if, say, you wanted to connect to an external Android device easily. Depending on the computer it can be horrendously slow. I also think we should be recommending the version of Ubuntu which has the software in rather than recommending downloading the software from outside the official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 2):

[This is the tool recommended by Canonical for Android development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/canonical-releases-ubuntu-developer.html)) it's now called Ubuntu Make and it's a command-line tool for installing the latest version of the Android Studio and SDK along with all the required dependencies. It focuses on the LTS versions of Ubuntu (and, therefore, backports any updates that would be useful for Android developers to the LTS release of Ubuntu) since they realize that Android developers don't want to have to upgrade Ubuntu every 6 months, want stability but also want an updated development environment.

Their focus is on the LTS releases of Ubuntu so I recommend you install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" (and then install Ubuntu Make and Android Studio as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)).

Answer (score 1):

I think either are a good option the only difference really would be the former has long term support being a developer my self I would lean towards the newer,

If you feel you don’t require the long term support and are competent perhaps you should also.

Comment: Or else wait 6 weeks, install Ubuntu 15.04 and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make`. Finally made it into the repos in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: apt-get dist-upgrade could be used at said point -- good information on the repo addition though!

Comment: Thanks for the other side of the argument @Wallermadev, I just think that since the Ubuntu Make people themselves recommend LTS then Android devs should probably use LTS!

Comment: Oh I would have to agree with you -- Although I feel i left the choice open either would be a very good choice for the ops needs as the question was what would give him a stable environment and not what will give him the most support.